# Django no me autocompleta los atributos en VSC

Tags: html, django, visual-studio, extensiones

Tengo la extensión de `Django` instalada pero aunque los `tag` de **HTML** me los atributos como class, id, etc... no me los autocompleta pero si me los detecta como abc

[image]

A pesar que agregué el

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "django-html": "html"
}
```

Sigue sin autocompletar correctamente los atributos

[image]